# How to connect frontend and backend Linux servers using cable?

Tags: networking, linux-networking

I'm trying to connect a web server A, with a database server B so that they have the least possible delay. Both servers run Debian, are on the same rack and are connected together by a cable on their second Ethernet port . here are the /etc/network/interfaces specs.

Server A (front)

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 11.22.33.5
        netmask 255.255.255.248
        network 11.22.33.3
        broadcast 11.22.33.10
        gateway 11.22.33.4
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

Server B (back)

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 11.22.77.8
        netmask 255.255.255.248
        network 11.22.77.6
        broadcast 11.22.77.23
        gateway 11.22.77.7
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 11.22.77.89
```

I am wondering what change(s) should I make to the interface files in order to make server A communicated directly with B through the cable.  Thanks

Comment: I highly recommend you use the `ipcalc` tool to assist you with choosing a suitable subnet for the connection. Better, use IPv6 for the link and you can use the link-local addresses.

Comment: Please make sure that eth0 is the actual port you want to use for the cross connect link. Choosing the wrong NIC will make you lose access.

Comment: If you want the least possible delay have you considered using Infiniband? it's latencies are an order of magnitude better than IP over 1GigE.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure the IP-addresses are on the same IP-network. In the config-snips you gave, they aren't.

So a valid configuration would be:

```
# Server A
iface eth0 inet static
        address 11.22.33.1
        netmask 255.255.255.248
        network 11.22.33.0
        broadcast 11.22.33.7

# Server B
iface eth0 inet static
        address 11.22.33.2
        netmask 255.255.255.248
        network 11.22.33.0
        broadcast 11.22.33.7
```

Learn about how IP-networks, their sizes and how netmasks work. The config-snips you gave make no sense at all. `network 11.22.33.3` is no network (networks always start with even numbers) and `11.22.77.23`
 is not the broadcast address of the network `11.22.77.6` with the netmask of `255.255.255.248`.

Answer (score 5):

Neither should have a gateway set, since there is no routing going on. Configure both interfaces to be on the same subnet. Then create a persistent static route on both machines that point to each other and is bound to the second interface. `man route` should help you with this part if you're unsure of how to do it.